# Use AWS API gateway to trigger python script running on EC2 instance and pass arguments

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to send inputs to my python script running on EC2 instance using the AWS API gateway. The workflow is as follows:

Users send an API request to AWS API gateway with parameters. The AWS API gateway then triggers the python script with the arguments passed in the API call.

However, I am unable to find any way in which the AWS API gateway can trigger a python script or pass an argument into an always running python script.

Any guidance on best practices to achieve this

Comment: Can you upload the python script to a Lambda function? You will be able to trigger the lambda function via API Gateway as a Lambda Proxy.

Comment: I tried that but hit the 50MB limit.

Comment: @nnay84 im trying to achieve the same. did your solution work? if so, please help me with steps.

Comment: @Vikrame I could not get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway can't interact directly with Python running in EC2.  API Gateway has HTTPS endpoints.  You will need to either have Python react to HTTPS requests directly or use the AWS Python SDK

Here's some general reading on Python and APIs

https://realpython.com/blog/python/api-integration-in-python/

Here's AWS boto3 SDK
https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/

I would check these out and when you feel like you're getting close ask another question and provide details on your code

Good luck!